# $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is used to check if links is clicked in browser ? how to check if link is cliked in email viewer?

Tags: http-referer

My purpose is : i send email to user that contains some links, if user click, it must go to my server to check and forward. in browser you can use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], but in email i don't know how ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you can use the same $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] if user check mail over web interface, and you can't get any mark about click in desktop email client.

Comment: you can't use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] in both cases

Comment: why no ? Web mail is just simple site